# How do I write to standard error in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, stderr

I'm having trouble figuring out how to both echo to the standard error stream and redirect the error stream of an executable.

I have come from a [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) and [Korn shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell) background, of which I would use;

```
# Write to stderr
echo "Error Message!" >&2

# Redirect stderr to file
/do/error 2>/tmp/err.msg
```

Comment: Are you talking about redirecting the output of an external executable, itself run from within powershell?

Comment: Worth noting, I found `Write-Error` to cause my script to terminate because I use `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`, which I find more valuable.

Answer (score 49):

Use `Write-Error` to write to stderr.  To redirect stderr to file use:

```
 Write-Error "oops" 2> /temp/err.msg
```

or

```
 exe_that_writes_to_stderr.exe bogus_arg 2> /temp/err.msg
```

Note that PowerShell writes errors as error records.  If you want to avoid the verbose output of the error records, you could write out the error info yourself like so:

```
PS> Write-Error "oops" -ev ev 2>$null
PS> $ev[0].exception
oops
```

`-EV` is short (an alias) for `-ErrorVariable`. Any errors will be stored in the variable named by the argument to this parameter.  PowerShell will still report the error to the console unless we redirect the error to `$null`.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I'm after, I don't want the stack-trace appearing, I just want to write to the error stream with a single error message.

Comment: Keep in mind that PowerShell is object-oriented and usually pushes objects around instead of text.  `Write-Error` is how you write to the error stream.  `echo` is just a compatibility alias for `Write-Object` which is how your place stuff on the output (stdout) stream.

Comment: In your updated version it still doesn't help, I want to be able to write a piece of text only to stderr, so that then I can have two redirects `cmd >stdout.log 2>stderr.log`. Consider the ability to `type` content and pipe to stderr, currently I believe it can't be done by the looks of things.

Comment: It seems `Write-Error "oops" -ev ev 2>&1 > $null` does not redirect anything to `stderr`. `Write-Error "oops"` works great but you're stuck with the verbose output.

Comment: @OhadSchneider I'm not sure what you mean here.  That command was meant to demonstrate how to "avoid" the stderr output from being displayed.  If you need that Error (stderr) info (but don't want it displayed), it is available in the `$ev` variable.

Comment: What I mean is that no only do you avoid the `stderr` output from being displayed, but `oops` is not actually redirected to stderr at all (I tried executing it externally and `oops` came out only in stdout).

Comment: "oops" is still being outputted to StdErr for me, despite being sent to StdOut and `$null`.

Comment: @OhadSchneider You mentioned "externally".  Are you trying to read PowerShell.exe's stderr output from a console exe? If so, that is a different beast.

Comment: @StevenVachon What do you mean exactly by "outputted to StdErr"?  Yes, the error record will be preserved in $Error but the message is not put in the Error stream.  You can see this like so `$ps = [PowerShell]::Create(); $null = $ps.AddScript('Write-Error Oops 2>&1 > $null'); $ps.Invoke(); $ps.Streams.Error`.  That shows there is nothing in the Error stream.  Now try that again but remove the `2>&1 > $null` part and you will see the error in the Error stream.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you ever want `Write-Error "oops" -ev ev 2>&1 > $null` if we all agree nothing is redirected to stderr? Besides, the OP was  clear in what he wanted to do - he wanted the equivalent of `echo "Error Message!" >&2` (namely write to the error stream) in PowerShell. `Write-Error` comes close (the only issue being you can't control the verbosity), but when you redirect it to $null you lose even that.

Comment: @OhadSchneider The last part of the answer was simply an example of how you could control the verbosity of output resulting from an error record going into the Error stream.  You don't lose the error record when you redirect it to $null if you use `-ev ev`.  It stores the error record in the variable `$ev`.  Plus it would also be available in the `$error` global.  If necessary, you can access the message of the error text later with `$ev.Exception.Message`.  I did update the answer to simplify the example to just `Write-Error oops -ev ev 2>$null`.

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand why you would ever do `Write-Error "oops" -ev ev 2>$null; $ev[0].exception` if the end result, as far as streams go, is the same as `echo oops`.

Comment: @OhadSchneider That was more of a pedagogical example and not practical.  A practical example would be `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Recurse *.dll -ev ev 2>$null`.  Get's the "red" out but you can access`$ev` for all the non-terminating errors generated by the command.

Comment: Ah, I see now. So the second example addressed the second part of the OP's question, about redirecting the error stream (not writing to it) - in this case directly to a variable to avoid the verbose error record.

Comment: The trouble with `Write-Error`, however, is that while the documentation claims this declares a "non-terminating error" it _will_ terminate your PowerShell script if you've changed `$ErrorActionPreference` to "Stop". `Write-Warning` may be a better option *but* it uses a different stream as indicated by mklement0's excellent answer.

Answer (score 47):

Note:

- This answer is about **writing to stderr from the perspective of the *outside world*** when a PowerShell script is called from there; while the answer is written from the perspective of the *Windows* shell, `cmd.exe`, it equally applies to *Unix* shells such as `bash` when combined with PowerShell Core.
- By contrast, **from *within* Powershell**, you should use `Write-Error`, as explained in [Keith Hill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998173/how-do-i-write-to-standard-error-in-powershell/4998713#4998713).
- Sadly, there is **no *unified* approach** that will work from both *within* PowerShell *and* from the outside - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064704/how-can-i-display-a-naked-error-message-in-powershell-without-an-accompanying/38064769#38064769) of mine for a discussion.

---

To add to [@Chris Sear's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998173/how-do-i-write-to-standard-error-in-powershell/5386791#5386791):

While `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine` should work in all hosts, **it doesn't (by default) write to stderr when invoked via `cmd.exe`**, such as from a batch file.
**`[Console]::Error.WriteLine`, by contrast, *always* does**.

So **if you want to write a PowerShell script that plays nicely in terms of output streams when invoked from `cmd.exe`**, use the following function, `Write-StdErr`, which uses `[Console]::Error.WriteLine`
in the regular PS / `cmd.exe` host (**console window**), and `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine` otherwise:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Writes text to stderr when running in a regular console window,
to the host''s error stream otherwise.

.DESCRIPTION
Writing to true stderr allows you to write a well-behaved CLI
as a PS script that can be invoked from a batch file, for instance.

Note that PS by default sends ALL its streams to *stdout* when invoked from
cmd.exe.

This function acts similarly to Write-Host in that it simply calls
.ToString() on its input; to get the default output format, invoke
it via a pipeline and precede with Out-String.

#>
function Write-StdErr {
  param ([PSObject] $InputObject)
  $outFunc = if ($Host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost') {
    [Console]::Error.WriteLine
  } else {
    $host.ui.WriteErrorLine
  }
  if ($InputObject) {
    [void] $outFunc.Invoke($InputObject.ToString())
  } else {
    [string[]] $lines = @()
    $Input | % { $lines += $_.ToString() }
    [void] $outFunc.Invoke($lines -join "`r`n")
  }
}
```

---

#### Optional background information: How the PowerShell CLI's output streams are seen by outside callers:

Internally, PowerShell has *more* than the traditional output streams (stdout and stderr), and their count has increased over time (try `Write-Warning "I'll go unheard." 3> $null` as an example, and read more at [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).

When interfacing with the outside world, PowerShell must *map* the non-traditional output streams to stdout and stderr.

**Strangely, however, PowerShell by default sends *all* its streams (including `Write-Host` and `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine()` output) to *stdout* when invoked from `cmd.exe`**, even though mapping PowerShell's error stream to stderr would be the logical choice. This behavior has been in effect since (at least) v2 and still applies as of v5.1 (and probably won't change for reasons of backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989#issuecomment-430859865)).

You can verify this with the following command, *if you invoke it from `cmd.exe`*:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "'out'; Write-Error 'err'; Write-Warning 'warn'; Write-Verbose -Verbose 'verbose'; $DebugPreference='Continue'; write-debug 'debug'; $InformationPreference='Continue'; Write-Information 'info'; Write-Host 'host'; $host.ui.WriteErrorLine('uierr'); [Console]::Error.WriteLine('cerr')" >NUL
```

The command writes to all PowerShell output streams (when you run on a pre-PowerShell-v5 version, you'll see an additional error message relating to `Write-Information`, which was introduced in PowerShell v5) and has `cmd.exe` redirect *stdout only* to `NUL` (i.e., *suppress* stdout output; `>NUL`).

You will see *no* output except `cerr` (from `[Console]::Error.WriteLine()`, which writes directly to stderr) - all of PowerShell's streams were sent to stdout.

**Perhaps even more strangely, it *is* possible to capture PowerShell's error stream, but *only with a redirection*:**

If you change `>NUL` to `2>NUL` above, it is exclusively PowerShell's *error stream* and `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine()` output that will be suppressed; of course, as with any redirection, you can alternatively send it to a *file*.
(As stated, `[Console]::Error.WriteLine()]` *always* outputs to stderr, whether the latter is redirected or not.)

To give a more focused example (again, run from `cmd.exe`):

```
powershell -noprofile -command "'out'; Write-Error 'err'" 2>NUL
```

The above only outputs `out` - `Write-Error`'s output is suppressed.

**To summarize**:

- Without any (`cmd.exe`) redirection or with *only* a *stdout* redirection (`>...` or `1>...`), PowerShell sends *all* its output streams to *stdout*.
- With a *stderr* redirection (`2>...`), PowerShell *selectively* sends its *error stream* to *stderr* (irrespective of whether stdout is also redirected or not).
- As a corollary, the following common idiom does *not* work as expected:

  `powershell ... >data-output.txt`
  This will not, as one might expect, send only *stdout* to file `data-output.txt` while printing *stderr* output to the terminal; instead, you'd have to use

  `powershell ... >data-output.txt 2>err-output.tmp; type err-output.tmp >&2; del err-output.tmp`

It follows that **PowerShell is aware of `cmd.exe`'s redirections and adjusts its behavior *intentionally***.
(This is also evident from PowerShell producing *colored* output in the `cmd.exe` *console* while stripping the color codes when output is redirected to a file.)

Comment: I am seeing PS7 send `$Host.UI.WriteErrorLine` output to stdout and not stderr even when called from within the pwsh shell.

Comment: @Marc: _Inside_ PowerShell, there is no such thing as stdout and stderr, only PowerShell's 6 streams vs. to-host output. _Outside_ PowerShell, `$Host.UI.WriteErrorLine` - as does `Write-Error` - writes to stdout _by default_, but you can _redirect it_ with `2>`, as explained in the answer. To write to the outside world's stderr _by default_, use `[Console]::Error.WriteLine()`, as recommended in the answer, at the expense of being able to capture such output _inside_ a PowerShell session.

Comment: I feel I'm swimming against the stream: how does PowerShell *intend* developers to capture error output between scripts? I want to call a script.ps1 and capture an error stream/object. Should I just throw? Setting `-ErrorVariable $foo` seems to have no effect on `$foo` regardless of any errors thrown or written,

Comment: @Marc: You can only use `-ErrorVariable` if the command is an _advanced_ script or function, or a compiled cmdlet, and then you must use `-ErrorVariable foo` - that is, you _mustn't use the `$` sigil_.

Comment: OK, but it's really weird that `./scriptlet.ps1 2>` doesn't capture errors while `run-cmdlet 2>` does.

Comment: @Marc: I don't understand the distinction. Inside PowerShell, anything that is written to the error stream can be redirected with `2>`, irrespective of whether it is a simple or advanced function/script or a cmdlet or even an external program writing to stderr. PowerShell commands write to the error stream either explicitly with `Write-Error` or implicitly by triggering non-terminating or statement-terminating errors.

Answer (score 45):

You probably want this:

```sh
$host.ui.WriteErrorLine('I work in any PowerShell host')
```

You might also see the following, but it assumes your PowerShell host is a console
window/device, so I consider it less useful:

```sh
[Console]::Error.WriteLine('I will not work in the PowerShell ISE GUI')
```

Comment: `WriteErrorLine` is a bad idea. Look at the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.writeerrorline%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): *This method writes a line to the error display of the host.* In other words, this is a **UI** method, that sometimes works as you expect and redirects to stderr, and sometimes (most times?) doesn't (see mklement0's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/67824). As Keith Hill says, `Write-Error` is the best option.