# How to generate same Output with Write-Error as with echo?

Tags: powershell

I've read about differences of `echo` (which is a `Write-Output`) and `Write-Error` but I have still issues with exceptions and stack traces.

The following sample demonstrates my issue:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
trap  {
    echo "Trap encountered. Exiting with 1. See errors below."
    echo $_ # This is a test
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_

    exit 1
}

BROKEN_COMMAND
```

I won't post the output as it is localized but the gist is:

- `echo` outputs "BROKEN_COMMAND" was not found to be a CmdLet etc and outputs the callstack of the **exact** location where the issue was found, above would be line 10 or so.
- `Write-Error` outputs the line "BROKEN_COMMAND" was not found to be a CmdLet too but then the callstack shows actually the line where the **Write-Error** statement is and not the proper callstack (line 5)

How can I properly write to the error channel? I've tried omitting `-ErrorRecord` but no effect.

I need the error channel for errors so dumping everything in echo and then writing "there has been an error" in the error channel is not a good option.

---

Update: I tested @MathiasR.Jessen hint with `throw` (actually `throw $_`).
This results however in an immediate exit of the program without a useful exit code in `$LASTEXITCODE`, which I require to properly signal the end. My `exit 1` is not executed and the throw terminates without proper exit code.

Comment: interesting reading: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2011/09/14/custom-errors/

Comment: Re-throw the error using `throw` (with no arguments) instead of `Write-Error $_` if you want to preserve the original callstack

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  throw did not work. Writing `throw $_` however fixed it :) I did not think about throw as I was in the trap and assumed recursion here.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this is actually still useless with `throw $_` since it exits my program there is no proper exit code specified, and I need exit codes when exceptions exit, this is quirky powershell behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [Writing to error stream in Powershell using Write-Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265890/writing-to-error-stream-in-powershell-using-write-error)

the write-error cmdlet will display your message followed by the line number of the write-error cmdlet itself.

in the linked question it was said that this behaviour chnaged at some point.

in either case.. try this instead
hidin in  `Get-Help About_Preference_Variables` is mention of the `$ErrorView` variable

NormalView (default)

```
Trap encountered. Exiting with 1. See errors below.
BROKEN_COMMAND : The term 'BROKEN_COMMAND' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\errors.ps1:11 char:1
+ BROKEN_COMMAND
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (BROKEN_COMMAND:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

C:\errors.ps1 : The term 'BROKEN_COMMAND' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\errors.ps1:6 char:6
+      Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (BROKEN_COMMAND:String) [Write-Error], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,errors.ps1
```

but if you set 
`$ErrorView = "CategoryView"`
you get

```
Trap encountered. Exiting with 1. See errors below.
ObjectNotFound: (BROKEN_COMMAND:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
ObjectNotFound: (BROKEN_COMMAND:String) [Write-Error], CommandNotFoundException
```

perhaps that is more useful

you may want to change your
    echo $_
to
    echo $_.tostring()

also see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/06/21/errorviewcategoryview/

its a shame you cant write your own error form like log4