# If-else inside a foreach doesn't return what I think it should

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, foreach

I have an array of servers that I need to loop through, and have an attribute assigned only to specific servers (this happens later in the script).

Here's the array:

```
$test = @('test_dc','test_fp','test_ts','test_ap')
```

In the array, I have a domain controller, file/print, terminal server, and application servers (in that order).

The only servers that should get the attribute are the fp, ts, and ap servers.

Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
foreach ($item in $test) {
  Write-Host $item "`n"
  Write-Host "Start IF here `n"
  if ($item.Name -like '*fp*') {
    Write-Host "Found $item"
  } else {
    Write-Host "ELSE `n"
    Write-Host '-=-=-=-=-'
  }
}
```

Here's the output from that:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop> .\scratch.ps1

test_dc

Start IF here

ELSE

-=-=-=-=-

test_fp

Start IF here

ELSE

-=-=-=-=-

test_ts

Start IF here

ELSE

-=-=-=-=-

test_ap

Start IF here

ELSE

-=-=-=-=- 
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop>
```

According to the way I think it *should* work, I should see this:

```
...
test_fp

Found test_fp
...
```

I've also tried this:

```
if ($test -contains '*fp') {
  Write-Host "Found $_"
} else {
  Write-Host 'end'
}
```

and I just get an empty line.

Comment: usage of the asterisk part of the string as if treating it as wildcard does not work in powershell, drop the asterisk and try it. Or use a regex pattern in that case.

Comment: `$item` is just a normal string, it has no `name` property. Change `$item.name -like '*fp*'` to `$item -like '*fp*'`

Comment: Is the only goal to see it on the screen? Because, that is all that Write-Host can do. It cannot be redirected.

Comment: @t0mm13b: The entire point of PowerShell's `-like` operator is to support wildcard patterns containing metacharacters such as `*` (asterisk). The only problem here is that the input is comprised of _strings_, and strings have no `.Name` property.

Comment: @lit it can be redirected, it was changed in PSv5 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523369/write-host-vs-write-information-in-powershell-5#comment64549666_38526931

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing extra info being written to host as you have indefinite writes for each item, regardless if it matches. Since you're including the `else` statement as well, you're going to see extra stuff written for the non-matched items. Your `foreach` loop also specifies the `name` attribute for the object, while your `$test` array only contains strings.

Here's what I updated it to to limit to only write the host name in your loop if it matches `*fp*`, otherwise writing your divider:

```
$test = @('test_dc','test_fp','test_ts','test_ap')
foreach ($item in $test) {
  if ($item -like '*fp*') {
    Write-Host "Found $item"
  } else {
    Write-Host '-=-=-=-=-'
  }
}
```

Running that will output this:

```
-=-=-=-=-
Found test_fp
-=-=-=-=-
-=-=-=-=-
```

Comment: Thank you!  I figured it was something like that, but I wasn't sure.  Just out of curiosity, I changed `-contains` to `-like` in the second example and the script returned 'Found' as I expected, but why didn't it return the found text, or anything, represented by `$_`?