# How to merge variables to one string and output to specific colum in CSV?

Tags: powershell

I made a script that generates usernames based on names out of a CSV. Now I want to export those usernames to the same CSV I got them, but in a third column that's named username. How do I merge the output and export them to my CSV? Can I capture the output of Write-Host? I just noticed that my Nachname.substring doesn't include the first letter, why is that?

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\Namen.csv -Header "Vorname","Nachname","Username" -Delimiter ';' 

Foreach($user in $users) {
    $number = Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 99
    $firstName = $user.Vorname.Substring(0,1)
    $lastName = $user.Nachname.Substring(0.7)
    $usernames = Write-Host "$($firstName)$($lastName)$($number)"
}
```

My CSV looks like this:

> Monika  Aldegar MAldegar57 
>   Iban    Ashok IAshok81 
>   Aelmaer Dusko ADukso15 
>   and so on...

now those are two columns for the first name and last name. I want the created username in the third column

Comment: Can you provide us a sample csv with 1 record and the output you expect?

Comment: @MartinBrandl sure, https://imgur.com/a/MkWt4ua. My script currently outputs the names like Mldegar29, Ishok41, Aukso22 and so on. Now I want to export those full usernames to the CSV in the third column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your CSV sample *as text*. Do not post screenshots on external resources that may vanish at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a litte error in

```
$lastName = $user.Nachname.Substring(0.7)
```

Should be:

```
$lastName = $user.Nachname.Substring(0,7)
```

For collecting your information you can use a custom object

```
$myobj = new-Object PSObject
```

and add it into a list:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$myList = @()
```

Then add properties into it:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $myobj -NotePropertyName Vorname -NotePropertyValue $firstname
Add-Member -InputObject $myobj -NotePropertyName Nachname -NotePropertyValue $lastname
```

Then assign your newly created username to a variable

```
$username=$firstName+$lastName+$number
```

And also add it into the object

```
Add-Member -InputObject $myobj -NotePropertyName Username -NotePropertyValue $username
```

If you have all the data you wanted to retrieve add the object into a list:

```
$mylist.add($myobj)
```

So in the end your script could look like:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\Namen.csv -Header   "Vorname","Nachname","Username" -Delimiter ';' 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$myList = @()
Foreach($user in $users) {
    $myobj = new-Object PSObject
    $number = Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 99
    $firstName = $user.Vorname.Substring(0,1)
    $lastName = $user.Nachname.Substring(0.7)
    Add-Member -InputObject $myobj -NotePropertyName Vorname -NotePropertyValue $user.Vorname
    Add-Member -InputObject $myobj -NotePropertyName Nachname -NotePropertyValue $user.Nachname
    $username=$firstName+$lastName+$number
    Add-Member -InputObject $myobj -NotePropertyName 
    Username -NotePropertyValue $username
    $mylist.add($myobj)
} 
$mylist | Export-CSV "YOURPATH" -Delimiter ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

You substring on the Nachname property uses a dot instead of a comma. You should also check for the length there in order to avoid an exception if the name is less then 7 characters. This is how I would implement it:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\Namen.csv -Header "Vorname","Nachname" -Delimiter ';'
$users | Select-Object *, @{e={'{0}{1}{2}' -f $_.Vorname.Substring(0,1), $_.Nachname.Substring(0, ([System.Math]::Min(7, $_.Nachname.Length))), (Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 99)}; l="UserName"}
```

**Sample output:**

```
Vorname Nachname UserName  
------- -------- --------
Monika  Aldegar  MAldegar94
Iban    Ashok    IAshok85
```

You probably want to save it back to a CSV by appending the following line to the script: 
| `Export-CSV "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Namen2.csv" -Delimiter ";"`

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot capture the output of `Write-Host`. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527767/1630171). [Also related](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/).

Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding a new column from values of existing columns.

```
$csv     = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Namen.csv'
$headers = 'Vorname', 'Nachname'
$delim   = ';'

(Import-Csv $csv -Header $headers -Delimiter $delim) |
    Select-Object *, @{n='Username';e={
        $number    = Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 99
        $firstName = $user.Vorname.Substring(0,1)
        $lastName  = $user.Nachname.Substring(0,7)
        "${firstName}${lastName}${number}"
    }} |
    Export-Csv $csv -NoType -Delimiter $delim
```

Note that the parentheses around the `Import-Csv` statement are required because you want to write the output back to the same file. Without them you'd end up with an empty file because `Export-Csv` would start writing before `Import-Csv` finished reading, thus effectively truncating the file.