# PowerShell Transcript is not capturing git output

Tags: git, powershell

I'm writing a script that will perform some git actions and I want to use `Start-Transcript` to monitor it.  The transcript is however missing most of the `git` output.

I've tried to pipe the `git` output to both `Out-Host` and `Out-Default` but neither work.

Here's my code...

```bsh
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
$TranscriptName = "PSTranscript_$DateTime"

Start-Transcript -Path ".\$TranscriptName.txt"

git --bare clone <GIT_REPO_URL> repo | Out-Default

Stop-Transcript
```

Here's my console output...

```
Transcript started, output file is .\PSTranscript_20191119_155424.txt
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 58975, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21457/21457), done.
remote: Total 58975 (delta 43348), reused 51727 (delta 37145)
Receiving objects: 100% (58975/58975), 70.46 MiB | 3.95 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (43348/43348), done.
Checking out files: 100% (3878/3878), done.
Transcript stopped, output file is .\PSTranscript_20191119_155424.txt
```

And here's what is captured in the transcript, note that some of the `git` output is missing

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20191119155424
Username: 
RunAs User: 
Configuration Name: 
Machine: 
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 20644
PSVersion: 5.1.17134.858
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17134.858
BuildVersion: 10.0.17134.858
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is .\PSTranscript_20191119_155424.txt
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20191119155457
**********************
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309 might help.

Comment: `Start-Transcript` should capture everything regardless of the output stream. However, it seems that piping `git` command output to `Out-Default` causes output to not be logged in the transcript.]

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect the conclusion that `Out-Default` should _never_ be called directly from user code, based on [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11135#issuecomment-556461374).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's **no reason to call `Out-Default` - just use your `git` command as-is**, and your problem will go away: both its stdout and stderr streams will be transcribed.

<sup>`git` writes *status* information to *stderr* by default, and the - mistaken - use of `Out-Default` affects stderr output specifically, as described in the bottom section.</sup>

The following example demonstrates that **both stdout and stderr output from external programs are captured in the transcript**:

```sh
$file = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

"--- DIRECT OUTPUT ---`n"

Start-Transcript $file

# Execute a command that produces
# both stdout and stderr output.
# Do NOT use Out-Default.
if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {  # Windows
  cmd /c 'echo hi & nosuch'
} else {                         # macOS, Linux
  sh -c 'echo hi; nosuch'
}

Stop-Transcript

"`n--- CORE CONTENT OF TRANSCRIPT ---"

# Print the core of the transcript.
((Get-Content -Raw $file) -split '(?m)^\*+\s*$')[2]

Remove-Item $file
```

On Windows, you'll see something like the following, demonstrating that both streams were captured:

```sh
--- DIRECT OUTPUT ---

Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp342C.tmp
hi
'nosuch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp342C.tmp

--- CORE CONTENT OF TRANSCRIPT ---

Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp342C.tmp
hi
'nosuch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

#### The purpose of the `Out-Default` cmdlet:

**[`Out-Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default) is *not* meant to be called from user code.**

Instead, it is meant to be used only by [PowerShell host applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/writing-a-windows-powershell-host-application), including by PowerShell itself.
It creates pretty-printed string representations of the output objects using [PowerShell's output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) and sends them to the host for display.

The reason that it is a public cmdlet is that you are allowed to *override* it in order to define a *custom* output formatter, although doing so is rare.

Overriding is as simple as defining an advanced `Out-Default` function in your session, which must have the same parameter declarations and pipeline-binding behavior. You can scaffold such a function via a *wrapper (proxy) function*, as  demonstrated in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375)). Note that in order to produce visible output from your function, you must send your custom-formatted strings either to the original `Out-Default` or use the *host APIs* to print them (`Write-Host`, in the simplest case).

---

#### Bug:

Your use of `Out-Default` - though ill-advised - should arguably still have worked.

While that is a moot point for `Out-Default`, given that it shouldn't be called directly, `Out-Host` exhibits the same problem (as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.6), and there *are* legitimate reasons to call `Out-Host`, namely to explicitly print to the display only (and doing so should not affect transcription behavior).

Specifically, if you use `Out-Host` explicitly, *stderr* output from *external programs* is unexpectedly not recorded in the transcript.
(By contrast, the problem doesn't surface with PowerShell commands.)

The problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #11134](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11134).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: I make a mistake in leaving the `Out-Default` in my original code.  This hits a bug in `Out-Default` that specifically affects `stderr`.  Removing the `Out-Default` resulted in fixing my script and it now successfully transcribes git output.

---

@VonC posted a very helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309) that pointed me in the right direction!

All that needed done was adding the `GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR` environment variable with the value `2>&1` to Windows User environment variables.

If you're on Windows, here's a nifty PowerShell command you can run to add the environment variable.

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR", "2>&1", "User")
```

Below is what my new transcript looks like...

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20191119165056
Username: 
RunAs User: 
Configuration Name: 
Machine: 
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 16440
PSVersion: 5.1.17134.858
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17134.858
BuildVersion: 10.0.17134.858
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is .\PSTranscript_20191119_165056.txt
Cloning into bare repository 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 58975, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21457/21457), done.
remote: Total 58975 (delta 43347), reused 51727 (delta 37145)
Receiving objects: 100% (58975/58975), 70.33 MiB | 6.04 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (43347/43347), done.
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20191119165115
**********************
```

Comment: Thanks! For my environment, I had to use this line, which should be functionalty equivalent:

 $env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = "2>&1"

Answer (score 2):

`Start-Transcript` should capture everything written to the console host regardless of which stream it writes to. However, I did notice that when I pipe a git command to `Out-Default`, I get NOTHING written to the transcript for that command, even though it displays to the console.

I can't explain why this happens, but remove `| Out-Default` from your clone command and it should log the output to the transcript.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, I was reading and expecting Out-Default to do the trick but experienced the same thing.  It does however seem that redirecting the output is doing the trick.

Comment: This is going to drive me absolutely nuts. I don't have that set on my workstation and I still get `git` output logged to the transcript unless I pipe it to `Out-Default`. I thought maybe it might be a quirk of using ConEmu as my console host but even using plain `powershell.exe` I get the same behavior.

Comment: Good points. Note that it's _stderr_ output from external programs, specifically, that isn't getting recorded, but the main point is indeed that there's no reason to use `Out-Default` to begin with.

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect the conclusion that `Out-Default` should _never_ be called directly from user code, based on [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11135#issuecomment-556461374). While the `Out-Default` behavior is therefore a moot point, the same problem (omitted stderr output from the transcript) affects `Out-Host` too, and `Out-Host` _does_ have legitimate uses.