# Odd differences in logging git commands to a Powershell Transcript

Tags: git, powershell

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942723/powershell-transcript-is-not-capturing-git-output/58943306) for the full context of the behavior I'm trying to understand.

My understanding of `Start-Transcript` is that all output streams are logged to the Powershell transcript once it is started. I can write to streams 1-6 and still expect to see the output in my transcript log. However, in the question I linked to above, I'm seeing some strangeness surrounding this I can't explain and would like to understand why the output is swallowed in this case, and in that OP's case, we were each seeing different behavior.

Basically, OP was trying to log `git clone | Out-Default` to their transcript log, and was getting nothing logged out to the transcript. The solution that worked for them was to set an environment variable to have `git` write to `stdout` instead of `stderr`. OP later stated that they had tried piping the `git` command to `Out-Default` to see if it made a difference, which it did not, so they're solution seems to be that "`git` outputs to stderr and does not get captured by `Start-Transcript`.

My experience differed, however. I do not have `git` configured to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, and can confirm this by attempting to assign the output of a git command to a variable (which doesn't work, as I expected). Yet I can simply call `Start-Transcript`, then call `git status`, and see that it logs to the transcript. However, when I run `git status | Out-Default`, I get the output to the console, but not logged to the transcript. Removing `Out-Default` seemed to be the solution for me, but not for OP.

I'm at a loss as to what is going on here. On my system it seems that piping `git` commands, and only `git` commands, to `Out-Default` does not allow the output to be logged to a transcript. I've tested other external programs with their `stderr` output and piping the output to `Out-Default` still allows the output to be transcribed. But not `git blah | Out-Default`. And I still don't understand why the other question's OP needed to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, but I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're seeing a *bug*** that surfaces under the following condition:

- a transcription (started with `Start-Transcript`) is ongoing
- an *external program* (such as `git`) is being called, and it outputs (also) to *stderr* (the standard error stream).
- the external-program call is piped to `Out-Default`.

The stderr output is then unexpectedly *not* recorded in the transcript.<sup>[1]</sup>

The problem has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11134), but it's important to note that:

- There's **no reason to call `Out-Default`** in this scenario, because the transcript by default records both stdout and stderr output from external programs.
- There's *generally* no reason to call `Out-Default` from user code; it is designed to be called by PowerShell host applications.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58958346/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Note that stderr output from external programs is generally treated differently than error output from PowerShell commands: unless redirected, stderr lines are printed to the display by default, without touching PowerShell's error stream (and therefore also without being recorded in `$Error`), because stderr cannot generally be assumed to represent *errors*, given that many programs - including `git` - use it to write *status* information too.</sup>