# How should i handle dism powershell errors?

Tags: windows, powershell, dism

Hello I tried to handle the errors from dism with cath.. but that didn't work that good. So my question is, how i can improve it.

```
function dotnet35 () {
    WriteLogNewScirpt "dotnet35"
    WriteLogInstruction "installing .Net 3.5 online"
    $Errorccured=$false
    $Error.Clear()
    try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'
        Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList {DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All} -verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden | Out-Default
    } catch {
        WriteLogError ".Net 3.5 could not be installed"
        WriteLogError "$Error"
        $Errorccured=$true  
    }
    if(!$Errorccured) {
        WriteLogPosisitive ".Net 3.5 installed"       
    } else {
        dotnet35offline
    }
}

function dotnet35offline () {
    WriteLogInstruction "installing .Net 3.5 offline"
    $Erroroccured=$false
    $Error.Clear()
    try {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'
        Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList {DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:c:\scripts\sources\features\sxs} -verb RunAs | Out-Default
    } catch {
        WriteLogError ".Net 3.5 could not be installed"
        WriteLogError "$Error"
        $Erroroccured=$true
    }
    if(!$Erroroccured) {
        WriteLogPosisitive ".Net 3.5 konnte offline installiert werden"
    }
}
```

Sorry for my translation i translated it quiet fast ^^

thanks in advance

Comment: Put `$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'` BEFORE you enter the `try{}` block

Comment: As currently written, the `Try-Catch-Finally` statement handles  merely  errors  of  `Start-Process` cmdlet itself  (not inside a child process started). Simply restart the script elevated and omit the `Start-Process` i.e. use `Try {dism …}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Terminating errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59502868/584676) only affect PowerShell functions and exceptions thrown in .NET libraries. If you want to check the result of an ***external command*** (such as an executable), you will need to check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable, which serves the same purpose as the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable in batch scripts. For example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath dism.exe -ArgumentList '/Online', '/Enable-Feature', '/FeatureName:NetFx3', '/All' -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden
if( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ){
  # Handle the error here
  # For example, throw your own error
  throw "dism.exe failed with exit code ${LASTEXITCODE}"
}
```

---

Also, don't call `Out-Default` in your code. [It's not designed for this use.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58958975/584676)