# Starting .ps1 Script from PowerShell with Parameters and Credentials and getting output from it

Tags: powershell, runas, start-process

I think my problem has a simple solution. But now i'm a bit confused. 
I have Java Code, that starts 1 Powershell Script. This Powershell Script must start other scripts.
Java -> 
 Powershell.ps1 -> 
                          Script1.ps1
                          Script2.ps1
                          Script3.ps1
                          Script....

Script1,2,..etc performing multiple tasks and return String Values.

I've tried 
Start-Process, Invoke-Command and Invoke-Expression

Assuming script1.ps1 is:

```
$a = 1+2
$a
```

Start-Process would work the best for me but im not getting the output:

```
$arguments = "C:\..\script1.ps1" + " -ClientName" + $DeviceName
$output = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList $arguments -Credential $credentials
$output
```

$output ist NULL.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) produces *no* output by default.

(The only way to make it produce output *directly* is to use `-PassThru`, which then doesn't return the *script's* output, but a `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance *representing the newly created process* - see below.)

**The only way to *capture output from your script* via `Start-Process` is to use the `-RedirectStandardOutput` and

`-RedirectStandardError` parameters to capture the script's output *as text*, in *files*.**<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>

You can then read those files in PowerShell *after the new process has completed*, which you can ensure in one of two ways:

- Also pass the `-Wait` switch to `Start-Process`, to make the invocation synchronous, which means that when `Start-Process` returns, the output has already been captured in the specified file(s).
- Use `-PassThru` to obtain a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance and pass it to [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) later (or use its `.WaitForExit()` method directly; property `.HasExited` can be used to check whether the process is still running).

Here's what may work in your situation:

```sh
$arguments = "-File C:\...\script1.ps1" + " -ClientName" + $DeviceName

# Launch the script in a new window running as the given user,
# capture its standard output in file ./out.txt,
# and wait for it to finish.
Start-Process -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput ./out.txt powershell -ArgumentList $arguments -Credential $credentials

"Running script1.ps1 produced the following output:"
Get-Content ./out.txt
```

The PowerShell CLI, regrettably, reports *all* of PowerShell's [6 output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), via *standard output* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375)), so the above captures *all* output from your script, including error output.

However, you can use, e.g., `-RedirectStandardError ./err.txt` to capture the error stream separately.

---

[1] **Calling another PowerShell instance** via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) offers **a *structured alternative* to capturing unstructured text** (the for-display output as it would print to the console, which is what happens by default):

**`-OutputFormat xml`** (or `-of xml` / `-o xml`) makes PowerShell format its output in CLIXML format, which is the same XML-based serialization format used in PowerShell remoting and background jobs for **serializing *rich objects***, which you can **"rehydrate" with a later [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml) call**.

Note: **For most complex objects there is a *loss of type fidelity***: that is, they are serialized as *emulations* of the original objects; in short as "property bags" without methods, which, however may be sufficient - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

Here's a quick demonstration, using a `[datetime]` instance, which *does* deserialize with type fidelity:

```sh
# Call Get-Date via the PowerShell CLI and save the output
# in CLIXML format in file ./out.xml
Start-Process -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput ./out.xml powershell '-of xml -c Get-Date'

# Import the CLIXML file and convert its content back to a [datetime] instance.
"Type of the CLIXML-serialized and deserialized `Get-Date` output:"
(Import-CliXml ./out.xml).GetType().FullName # -> System.DateTime
```

<sup>[2] The character encoding of the output files is determined by the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which reflects the current console output code page, which defaults to the system's active legacy *OEM* code page.</sup>