# Using Perl to check installed Powershell modules

Tags: powershell, perl

Long Story short Im working with multiple versions of PCs and Powershell versions, I need to install updates on as machines automated. I have a script that installs a module on windows 10 machines, and installs the modules on the other machines. I would like to check if the required modules are installed and imported, but Im new to perl and cant find anything.

```
print "Installing new updates\n";
my ( $osvername, $major, $minor, $id ) = Win32::GetOSVersion();
if($major == 10 )
{
    my $ps_path = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe';
    system("$ps_path -command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -force");
    system("$ps_path -command Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -force");
    system("$ps_path -command Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate -force");
    system("$ps_path -command Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -AcceptAll");
    system("$ps_path -command Set-ExecutionPolicy Default -force");
}
else
{
    system("$gRootDir\\Tools\\WUInstall.exe /install");
}
```

Comment: You didn't identify any problem

Comment: Shouldn't it be way easier to actually do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *single* `system()` call:

```perl
system("
  $ps_path -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command \"
    \\\$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -force
    Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate -force
    Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -AcceptAll
  \"
");
```

Note:

- `system()` passes all output streams through to the terminal (console).

  - As an aside: unfortunately, PowerShell reports even *error* messages via *stdout*, though you can selectively capture them with a `2>` redirection - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375).
- You can inspect `$? >> 8` for the exit code, though in the case of failure it will always be `1` in this case.
- PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameters:

  - `-NoProfile` prevents unnecessary loading of the PowerShell profiles, which are normally only needed for *interactive* sessions.
  - `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` changes the execution policy for *this invocation (process) only*, which obviates the need to restore the policy later.
- `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` tells PowerShell to abort processing if and when any error should occur. In the context of a CLI call, this translates to a process exit code of `1`.