# Get output from `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` including `WhatIf`

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I want to write a wrapper around `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` in PowerShell. So lets assume the following script:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name 'test' `
    -ResourceGroupName 'rg-test' `
    -TemplateFile .\main.bicep `
    -TemplateParameterFile .\parameters\parameters.json `
    -Verbose `
    -WhatIf
```

This will output something like this:

```sh
VERBOSE: Using Bicep v0.4.1008
...
What if: Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "rg-test".
```

So the problem here is that I won't get any results from the `WhatIf`. I guess its because `WhatIf` runs a different process in the background.

So is there a way to capture the output of the `WhatIf`?

Comment: I don't think you can, `-WhatIf` doesn't go to any of the PowerShell [output Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2#:~:text=PowerShell%20provides%20multiple%20output%20streams,the%20associated%20cmdlet%20or%20redirection.&text=PowerShell%20supports%20the%20following%20output%20streams.) similar to `$testVar = [console]::WriteLine('hello') *>&1` cannot be captured either.

Comment: `Start-Transcript` can capture it actually but I don't think that's your intent, you want it on a variable right?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thx for the suggestions. I think i can‘t do it in a clean way. But good to know some workarounds ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **output produced by using the [common `-WhatIf` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-whatif) can unfortunately *not* be captured *in-session*** - it prints directly to the *console* (host).

The only **workaround** is to **use PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)** (`powershell.exe` for Windows PowerShell, `pwsh` for PowerShell (Core) 7+)

```
$whatIfAndVerboseOutput = powershell.exe -c @'
  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name 'test' `
    -ResourceGroupName 'rg-test' `
    -TemplateFile .\main.bicep `
    -TemplateParameterFile .\parameters\parameters.json `
    -Verbose `
    -WhatIf
'@
```

<sup>Not the use of a verbatim [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) to avoid the need for escaping the embedded quote characters.</sup>

**Caveats**:

- Such a call is expensive.
- Since a new, independent session that runs in a *child* process is created, it knows nothing about the state of the *caller* (except that it inherits environment variables).

  - Assuming the argument data types are simple enough, you can use an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (`"..."`) to embed values from the caller in the command text.

    - Note: As of PowerShell 7.2, PowerShell's CLI, when a command *string* is passed to `-c` (`-Command`) - which is the only option when calling *from outside PowerShell* - not only sends direct-to-console output to stdout, but *all* of its output streams there as well - including *error* - which is problematic: see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375) for details; here, this means that the `-Verbose` output is captured as well.
  - Alternatively, for *better* - but not complete - type fidelity, pass a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to `-c` (`-Command`) instead of a string, to which you can pass values from the caller with `-args`. Note that using a script block is only an option when also calling *from* Powershell and that doing so will insert an *empty line* after each what-if output message.

    - Note: The script-block approach limits the output that is mapped to the caller's success stream (via stdout) to direct-to-console output (such as from `-WhatIf`) and the command's *success*-stream output. Output to any of the other streams is mapped to the corresponding streams of the caller, though you can use redirections *inside* the script block to merge streams into the success output stream.
      In the case at hand, the `-Verbose` output would be passed through to the caller's verbose stream by default and would therefore *not* be captured in a variable capturing the command output. However, placing `4>&1` inside the script block would include it.

Comment: I‘ll mark this as the answer although it does not soöve it for me. Still good to know whats possible. Thx!

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderSchmidt. In what way does it not solve your problem?

Comment: I want to use it in a powershell module. The problem is that users will not accept the caveats you mention and that I‘m pretty sure that running this under Linux will freak out the system. Its too shaky I think.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt, the host OS shouldn't make a difference; the call is robust, as long as you know that the command being submitted has all necessary inputs and can auto-load modules it depends on in the new session. When it comes to regular, _non_-`WhatIf` _success_ output, however, you'll lose type fidelity - but you can limit the CLI call to the `-WhatIf` scenario. But, of course, if a CLI call is too expensive, this solution isn't an option. Out of curiosity: how would your module expose this functionality, and why does the module itself need to capture `-WhatIf` output?

Comment: Thx. I want this for 2 reasons: 1) the user should get at least the same output as withbthe normal command 2) i wanted to parse the output to enable my module to warn on creations and delegions optionally. Maybe i‘ll give it a try. Inwill post my experiences as an answer here.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt Did you already do your experiences? I would be interested in the results.